# How do i use a custom Font ( ttf - File ) in Ionic 2 ?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

Im trying to install and use a custom font ( Chewy.ttf ) in Ionic 2 
i already tried to use it like css with `@font-face {
  font-family: Chewy;
  src: url(../../www/assets/fonts/Chewy.ttf);
}`
And in the Browser it works just fine but when I build it 
it won't work anymore 
Thankful for any help

Answer (score 6):

first put your font file in src/assets/fonts/name.ttf path.
then in src/app/app.scss

```
@font-face {
font-family: name;
src: url(../assets/fonts/name.ttf) format("ttf");
font-weight: 200
}
body {
font-family: name !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For now you can use [Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/), for example download this one : https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v11/yQiAaD56cjx1AooMTSghGfY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.woff2

Just copy the file downloaded to the folder "www/assets/fonts" and rename it if you want.

In the file app.scss copy this code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Raleway";
src: url("../assets/fonts/Raleway.woff2") format("woff2");
}
```

you can now use your new font

```
H1 {
font-family : "Raleway";}
```

Comment: @InzamamMalik for ionic 3 copy the code into the file variables.scss, you can use any font, but be sure to get all font files